# "BASE64DecoderStream" gives error for javax-mail dependency

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I recently changed the dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

because Java 8 doesn't support 1.4 version as it uses TLS 1.0.

After changing the dependency this code starts giving error.
Error code:

```java
if (p.getContentType().contains("image/")) {
    File f = new File("image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));
    
    com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream test = (com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream) p
            .getContent();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = test.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

Eclipse suggestion error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream cannot be resolved to a type
    - com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: FWIW: recent updates of Java 8 (and all of 11 up) _by default_ don't support TLS1.0, but you _can_ re-enable it. However, good practice nowadays calls for _servers_ not to allow you to connect using it (or SSL3), and while not all servers follow good practice quickly, some do by now and more will over time, so upgrading your client remains a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong dependency. You have only added the JakartaMail **API**. You should use the JakartaMail 1.6.x **implementation**:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.7</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency does include `com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream`.

As an aside, instead of what you're doing now (using `getContent()` and casting to an implementation-specific class), you could also use `Part.getInputStream()`:

```java
try (var in = p.getInputStream()) {
    in.transferTo(output);
}
```

Also, your use of `DataOutputStream` is suspect, as you don't seem to be using any `DataOutputStream` specific methods, so using the `BufferedOutputStream` directly should be sufficient.

Comment: thanks using the wrong dependecy this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
if (p.getContentType().contains("image/")) {
    Path imageFile  = Path.of("image" + Instant.now().toEpochMilli() + ".jpg");
    try(OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(imageFile)) {
        p.getInputStream().transferTo(out);
    }
}
```

would illustrate the comments between me and @Mark Rotteveel. Essentially what Mark has already posted, with further adjustments to the date handling and try-with-resources

Comment: `getContent()` returns `Object`, so the type of the value would need to be checked and cast, and depending on the Jakarta Activation providers on the classpath, `getContent()` might return something else. I recommend to use `p.getInputStream()` instead.

Comment: Ah right thanks. Will adjust